# Is a function a homeomorphism if $x_n \to x $ iff $f(x_n) \to f(x) $ on a separable metric space?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove an embedding result. To complete that task I need an auxiliary result that is topological in nature and, perhaps, not even that difficult. but I am concerned about overlooking or over-simplifying things.

To summarize my issue as much as possible. I have found a function $f: (S, d) \mapsto ([0, 1]^\infty, \rho) $ with  $(S, d) $ a separable metric space. The function $f $ is  such that
$$ s_n \to s \quad \mbox{if and only if} \quad f(s_n) \to f(s) $$
as $n \to \infty. $

I need to prove that this $f $ is a homeomorphism. The condition above yields the continuity of $f, $ clearly. It also yields the fact that $f $ is $1-1. $ and hence it has an inverse from the image space. But, is it possible to conclude that $f^{-1} $ is continuous too?

I realize that $f[S] $ is separable and I wonder if I could repeat the same type of argument for $f^{-1} $ this time, to prove its continuity using sequences, but I am not too confident in my ability not to screw this up.

Could anyone with more abilities than mine  help me close this argument? Thank you.

Maurice

Comment: By "homeomorphism" do you really mean "homeomorphism when considered as a map from $S$ to $f(S)$?"

Comment: yes, that is usually the requirement as there is no guarantee that the map is onto the space and normally the best one can do is to restrict to the problem to $f(S). $

Answer (score 1):

First, $f:S\to f(S)$ is injective : let $x,y \in S$, such that $f(x)=f(y)$. $S$ is separable so that there exists $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$. Now, $f(x_n) \to f(x) = f(y)$, hence $x_n \to y$. If your space is Haussdorf, then $x=y$.

It follows that $f:S\to f(S)$ is bijective. Moreover, $f^{-1}:f(S)\to S$ is continuous.

Indeed, let $u_n,u\in f(S)$ such that $u_n \to u$, ie: there exists $(x_n),x \in S$ such that $u_n=f(x_n) \to u=f(x)$. By hypothesis, $x_n \to x$, that is $f^{-1}(u_n)\to f^{-1}(u)$ which is what was needed.